# SQL Combine data from two different date ranges into one result set

Tags: sql-server-2008

Using SqlServer 2008, I have a temp table (#tmpAllSales) that captures all sales for a year.  I would like to create a SELECT statement that contains sales for the year as well as sales for the last quarter.

Something like this (@StartDate & @EndDate are defined as the start/end of a quarter):

```
--QTD Sales By Company
SELECT
    Company,
    SUM(Call) as TotalCallsQTD,
    SUM(Call) - SUM(SoldCall) as FreeCallsQTD,
    SUM(SalableCall) as SalesRelatedCallsQTD,
    SUM(SoldCall) as SoldCallsQTD
FROM
    #tmpAllSales
WHERE
    CalledOn between @StartDate and @EndDate
GROUP BY
    Company

--COMBINED WITH BASED ON Company

--YTD Sales By Company
SELECT
    Company,
    SUM(Call) as TotalCallsYTD,
    SUM(Call) - SUM(SoldCall) as FreeCallsYTD,
    SUM(SalableCall) as SalesRelatedCallsYTD,
    SUM(SoldCall) as SoldCallsYTD
FROM
    #tmpAllSales
GROUP BY
    Company
ORDER BY
    Company
```

Each separate query gives the results I want but I don't know how to combine into one result set.

**EDIT**

I didn't make it clear in my original post that I would like to get all the results on one row per company.  I am using this in an Excel macro so it would be great if all the info was on one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Period = 'QTD',
    Company,
    SUM(Call) as TotalCallsQTD,
    SUM(Call) - SUM(SoldCall) as FreeCallsQTD,
    SUM(SalableCall) as SalesRelatedCallsQTD,
    SUM(SoldCall) as SoldCallsQTD
FROM
    #tmpAllSales
WHERE
    CalledOn between @StartDate and @EndDate
GROUP BY
    Company
UNION ALL
SELECT
    Period = 'YTD',
    Company,
    SUM(Call) as TotalCallsYTD,
    SUM(Call) - SUM(SoldCall) as FreeCallsYTD,
    SUM(SalableCall) as SalesRelatedCallsYTD,
    SUM(SoldCall) as SoldCallsYTD
FROM
    #tmpAllSales
GROUP BY
    Company
ORDER BY
    Period, Company;
```

If you want them as a single row for each Company, then:

```
;WITH q AS
(
    SELECT
        Company,
        SUM(Call) as TotalCallsQTD,
        SUM(Call) - SUM(SoldCall) as FreeCallsQTD,
        SUM(SalableCall) as SalesRelatedCallsQTD,
        SUM(SoldCall) as SoldCallsQTD
    FROM
        #tmpAllSales
    WHERE
        CalledOn between @StartDate and @EndDate
    GROUP BY
        Company
), y AS 
(
    SELECT
        Company,
        SUM(Call) as TotalCallsYTD,
        SUM(Call) - SUM(SoldCall) as FreeCallsYTD,
        SUM(SalableCall) as SalesRelatedCallsYTD,
        SUM(SoldCall) as SoldCallsYTD
    FROM
        #tmpAllSales
    GROUP BY
        Company
)
SELECT q.Company, qTotalCallsYTD = q.TotalCallsYTD, etc...,
    yTotalCallsYTD = y.TotalCallsYTD, etc...
FROM q INNER JOIN y
ON q.Company = y.Company
ORDER BY q.Company;
```

Comment: This works but I didn't think of the results I would get.  This gives me two rows for each company one for YTD and one for QTD.  Is there a way to combine the data into one row for each company with all the columns (ie, Company, TotalCallsQTD, FreeCallsQTD, SalesRelatedCallsQTD, SoldCallsQTD, TotalCallsYTD, FreeCallsYTD, SalesRelatedCallsYTD, SoldCallsYTD).  I am using this in an Excel macro so it would help greatly if everything is in one row per company.

Comment: I did up vote this solution as it does answer the question but not with the results I want.